# Some conflicts were found in the installation area

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded the new patch update for Android Studio 2.2 today but the update was failed with the below error:

Update Error:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just clicked the `Cancel` and the update continue without any problem.

Comment: The update got canceled while pressing the cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround, try deleting or moving the file that is causing the conflict namely "gradle" in the specified directory to another folder when the Update starts NOT BEFORE! That may work for you.